# why laravel is not returning identify of a specific id

Tags: php, mysql, laravel

I have a problem in Laravel where I want to with a specific package to show something to these users?!
This is the existing code:

```
$package = DB::table('users')->where('package_id', '=', '2')->value('*');
```

And this brings me back all users with all the packages, but I just want the user with package number 2 and show something??

This is a query on the controller.
On the frontend, I just examined the variable.

Thanks guys

Comment: You should provide a table structure (`SHOW CREATE TABLE users`) and the query this code generates and provide PHP code, then we have a better picture..

Comment: *"And this brings me back all users with all the packages, but I just want the user with package number 2 "* i assume you mean that you only want users with package_id = 2 and don't have other package_id's ? if yes read [Why should I provide an MCVE for what seems to me to be a very simple SQL query?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query) for providing example data and expected results.

Answer (score 2):

`$package = DB::table('users')->where('package_id', '=', '2')->get()` should suffice.

I can't see the advantage of appending `value('*')` in this scenario

Comment: If I put get() always returning me users with the different package, but I just want users with package number 2

Comment: Realllllly? You will need to show some data/table structure. Also, try putting `dump($package);` after the query

Comment: Thank you, will help me with the result

Answer (score 0):

Try this... I hope it will work sure

```
$package = DB::table('users')->select('*')->where('package_id', '=', '2')->get();
```

Comment: Thanks mate but give me the collection again

Comment: Collection {#313 ▼
  #items: array:3 [▼
    0 => {#321 ▶}
    1 => {#322 ▶}
    2 => {#314 ▶}
  ]
}

Answer (score 0):

> And this brings me back all users with all the packages, but I just
>   want the user with package number 2

I assume you mean you only want to get users with `package_id 2` and nothing else.

If so the needed SQL query is harder. 
**Note that the query and demo is based on the information you have provided which is not alot**

**Query**

```
SELECT 
 *
FROM 
 users 
WHERE
 users.id IN (

  SELECT
    users.id 
  FROM
   users 
  GROUP BY
   users.id
  HAVING 
     SUM(users.package_id = 2) = 1
   AND
     COUNT(users.package_id = 2) = 1   
)
```

**Result**

```
| id  | package_id |
| --- | ---------- |
| 1   | 2          |
| 3   | 2          |
```

**Also note that this query assumes that package_id's within user_id's are unique.**

see [demo](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/oZHVeeTFdPwaKiEStvYNhn/1)

Comment: And this is the result I need, I'll try to do something now

Answer (score 0):

**With DB Facade**

```
$packages = DB::table('users')->where('package_id', '=', '2')->get();
```

**With Eloquent**

```
$packages = User::where('package_id', '2')->get();
```

**Blade**

```
@if($packages->count() > 0) //or @if(!$packages->isEmpty())
  // if part
@else
  // else part
@endif
```

Remember `get()` method always return collections

`first()` method return instance of a model

If you are using `first()` method instead of `get()` then you can handle something like that

**Controller**

```
$package = User::where('package_id', '2')->first();
```

**Blade**

```
@if($package) //or @if(!is_null($package))
  // code...
@endif
```

Comment: It is a good query but how to test this maybe it's a better question?

Comment: this is how I did it
@if($package)
  something
@endif

Comment: `@if($package)` always return true because `get` method return collections. check my updated post